# ProvisioningError installing Samba

Tags: samba

I'm trying to install samba, but it fails:

```
kavinlu@kavinlu-IT:/etc/init.d$ sudo apt-get -f install samba4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdcerpc-server0 libdcerpc0 libgensec0 libregistry0 libsamba-policy0 python-samba samba4-common-bin
Suggested packages:
  bind9 phpldapadmin samba-gtk swat2
Recommended packages:
  samba4-dsdb-modules
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdcerpc-server0 libdcerpc0 libgensec0 libregistry0 libsamba-policy0 python-samba samba4 samba4-common-bin
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgensec0.
(Reading database ... 207432 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libgensec0 (from .../libgensec0_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdcerpc0.
Unpacking libdcerpc0 (from .../libdcerpc0_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libregistry0.
Unpacking libregistry0 (from .../libregistry0_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdcerpc-server0.
Unpacking libdcerpc-server0 (from .../libdcerpc-server0_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libsamba-policy0.
Unpacking libsamba-policy0 (from .../libsamba-policy0_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package python-samba.
Unpacking python-samba (from .../python-samba_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package samba4-common-bin.
Unpacking samba4-common-bin (from .../samba4-common-bin_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package samba4.
Unpacking samba4 (from .../samba4_4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up libgensec0 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdcerpc0 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libregistry0 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdcerpc-server0 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsamba-policy0 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-samba (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up samba4-common-bin (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Administrator password will be set randomly!
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
ProvisioningError: guess_names: 'realm =' was not specified in supplied /etc/samba/smb.conf.  Please remove the smb.conf file and let provision generate it
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What's going wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: try apt-get -f install to force an install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error. Then try apt-get upgrade again, apt-get -f install back and forth until only the package that has the error is left.

Comment: I try apt-get -f install but is error.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem in this way:

1. Use this `smb.conf`:

   ```
   # Global parameters
   [global]
       workgroup = One
       realm = One
       netbios name = Klaptop11-10
       security = share
   ```
2. Install the `samba-dsdb-modules` package. To deal with dependencies, install all these together: `samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba4 samba4-clients samba4-common-bin`

All my samba-related packages are listed here, just in case:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep smb

ii  **libpam-smbpass**                         2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1                 pluggable authentication module for Samba
ii  **libsmbclient**                           2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1                 shared library for communication with SMB/CIFS servers
ii  **python-smbc**                            1.0.10-0ubuntu2                          Python bindings for Samba clients (libsmbclient)

$ dpkg -l | grep samba

ii  **libsamba-hostconfig0**                   4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 Samba host configuration library
ii  **libsamba-policy0**                       4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 Samba policy management
ii  **libsamba-util0**                         4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 Samba utility function library
ii  **python-samba**                           4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 Python bindings for Samba
ii  **samba-common**                           2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1                 common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  **samba-common-bin**                       2:3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.1                 common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  **samba-dsdb-modules**                     4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 Samba Directory Services Database
ii  **samba4**                                 4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 SMB/CIFS file, NT domain and active directory server (version 4)
ii  **samba4-clients**                         4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 client utilities from Samba 4
ii  **samba4-common-bin**                      4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1 Samba 4 common files used by both the server and the client
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the samba4 package - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba4/+bug/832465

If you don't need Active Directory DC functionality, I would recommend installing samba 3 (the stable release), and removing samba 4. Samba 3 is in the "samba" package, not the "samba4" package.

Comment: Sorry，Still so.

Comment: You will also need to uninstall Samba4 if you install Samba3, of course.

Answer (score 0):

actual bug is >> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba4/+bug/857394 <<

But I fixed it by removing reference to the domain controller and adding a line for security, as well making the workgroup and realm the same (in my case they're both called "One" (without quotes)

So the start of my basebones smb.conf reads thus:

```
    # Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = One
    realm = One
    netbios name = Klaptop11-10
    security = share
```

No idea if that's right in terms of samba usage, but I was going to configure it afterwards anyway, all I wanted initially was to stop it erroring constantly. Which this did.